# ag-grid, search text not working with cellRenderer applied columns

Tags: angular

Have few columns on grid having cellRenderer applied. For e.g Column for country is actually having country code, however with cellrenderer I am manipulating the content to countryflag+country name. I am displaying country code on tooltip. Now if I search by  country name, it will not filter the grid, whereas if I filter by country code, it will. Is there a way I can enble filter on the actual text displayed  as column content?

GRID OPTIONS:

```
enableSorting: true,
      enableFilter: true,
      enableColResize: true,
      enableBrowserTooltips: true,
      rowDragManaged: true,

 {
      headerName: "Country",
      field: "COUNTRY",
      cellRenderer: this.countryCellRenderer,
      tooltipField: "COUNTRY",
    },
```

[image]

UPDATE:

changed column defn as below:

```
  {
      headerName: "Country",
      field: "COUNTRY",
     cellRenderer: this.countryCellRenderer,
     getQuickFilterText: function(params) {
      return params.value.name;
  },
```

still NO LUCK!

SOLVED WITH BELOW CODE!!!!!!!!:

```
  headerName: "Country",
          field: "COUNTRY",
          cellRenderer: this.countryCellRenderer,
          getQuickFilterText: function (params: any) {
            if (params.value.length>2) {return params.value;}
            if (params.value.length===2){
              const countries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scanCountries'));
              var found = countries.filter(function (countries) { return countries.alpha2_Country_Code == params.value });
              return found[0].Country_Name;
            }       

          },
          tooltipField: "COUNTRY",
        },
```

Comment: Is it solved or you are still looking for a solution ?

Comment: Solved and solution is updated in the original post...Thanks